# Browser doesnt cache image. It requests again same image if it has different alt

Tags: html, browser, image, browser-cache

Here is the situation

In the same page, for the first pageview:

```
<img src="default_image.jpg" alt="john">
<img src="default_image.jpg" alt="george">
.
.
.
.
<img src="default_image.jpg" alt="you-name-it">
```

Using firebug, i see Firefox requesting the default_image.jpg many times. In this example, one request for alt="John", one for alt="George"....and list goes on.

I expected that browser would just have to make one request, for the file "default_image.jpg" and then use it for displaying every img with that src.

My question:

WHY is this happening
and HOW can i prevent it. My goal is to be able to have the same img src="..." with different alt values many times in a page but browsers will request it one time only.

NO JS/JQUERY. I'm looking for plain html solution (i hope it's not some rfc limitation)

p.s. i first noticed it when i saw different loading times of these images. i was expecting all the same src img's to load at once, but they didn't. the only difference between them are the alt tags, so that's where i put the blame on.

Comment: You can try a CSS background, instead of an inline image.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's not just a display issue, i need img to be present in the markup... :(